# How to simulate Win+D in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have just started using AutoHotkey on my Windows 7 and love it but have run into a problem in creating a script to minimize/un-minimize active window.  The problem is that the windows command that does that is the windows key + D so in creating the script, the minute I hit the windows key, the start menu lights up and I'm unable to use it as part of the script.  What is the solution?

Comment: Can you provide an example script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to simulate the following keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

To do so in [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com), use the [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) command.

You can use the Windows key modifier [`#`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm):

```
Send, #d
```

or you can be explicit:

```
Send, {LWin Down}d{LWin Up}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will give it a try.  Can you tell me how I can use the left and right arrows as part of a script?  I really appreciate knowing that # represents the Windows key.  How can I award you points?

Comment: You can **accept** my answer by clicking the **check mark ✓** below the **upvote ▲** and **downvote ▼** arrows on the left. This will award us both points and let the community know that this question has been answered. Welcome to Super User! :)